# X11 Why I can't draw any text?

Tags: c, linux, text, x11

I'm trying to learn X11. It's very hard to me, because I don't have experience with window applications on Linux. 
I wrote some simple code and I can't resolve this not visible text problem.
Everything is working good probably, when I was trying to draw rectangle with DrawRectangle function it was working. 
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
int main()
{
Display* myDisplay;
Window myWindow;
int myScreen;
GC myGC;
XEvent myEvent;
unsigned long black, white;
char* hello = "Hello world!";
XFontStruct* myFont;

if((myDisplay = XOpenDisplay(NULL)) == NULL)
{
    puts("Error in conneting to X Server!");
    return -1;
}
myScreen = DefaultScreen(myDisplay);
black = BlackPixel(myDisplay, myScreen);
white = WhitePixel(myDisplay, myScreen);

myWindow = XCreateSimpleWindow(myDisplay, RootWindow(myDisplay, myScreen), 0, 0, 640, 320, 5, black, white);

XSelectInput(myDisplay, myWindow, ExposureMask);

XClearWindow(myDisplay, myWindow);
XMapWindow(myDisplay, myWindow);

myGC = XCreateGC(myDisplay, myWindow, 0, 0);
XSetForeground(myDisplay, myGC, black);
XSetBackground(myDisplay, myGC, white);

myFont = XLoadQueryFont(myDisplay, "-Misc-Fixed-Medium-R-Normal--7-70-75-75-C-50-ISO10646-1");
XSetFont(myDisplay, myGC, myFont->fid);

while(1)
{
    XNextEvent(myDisplay, &myEvent);

    if(myEvent.type == Expose)
    {
        XClearWindow(myDisplay, myWindow);
// HERE I DONT KNOW WHY IT DOESNT WORK!
        XDrawString(myDisplay, myWindow, myGC, 0, 0, hello, strlen(hello)); 
    }   
}

XFreeGC(myDisplay, myGC);
XDestroyWindow(myDisplay, myWindow);
XCloseDisplay(myDisplay);

return 0;
}
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: As a sidenote: you are aware X11 is currently being replaced by Wayland? (es, I know this will take years, if not decades)  I don't want to talk you into something, but wouldn't learning a more modern graphics system be better?

Comment: @Olaf Ooo, good to know it. But i saw many application wroted in X11, and it is probably the basic of basics in linux window programming, and I wanna learn it. Do you see resolve of my problem?

Comment: Today, X11 is not much used that way. In practice, toolkits (like GTK or Qt) are drawing pixmaps client-side, and transmitting that pixmap to the X11 server.

Comment: BTW, I guess that your font path (argument to `XLoadQueryFont`) is incorrect. Check with `xlsfonts`. And you should handle all sorts of events, including those for errors ([`XErrorEvent`](ftp://www.x.org/pub/current/doc/man/man3/XErrorEvent.3.xhtml))

Comment: BTW, I recommend first learning how to develop GUI applications with a toolkit (like [GTK](http://gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io/)) and only later dive into X11 internals.

Comment: @Davey: As others pointed out, X11 is hardly programmed directly. Use a toolkit (I can recommend QT, others prefer GTK). They abstract from the grapfic system, QT e.g. runs on Windows, Mac and Linux/Framebuffer (typical on embedded devices). Btw.: That covers Wayland, too. Also note that the drawing primitives of X11 are not used by thoses toolkits. Some more research would be a good idea.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks, i probably should learn API first

Comment: @Davey: what do you mean by learning an API? "everything" is an API! Even libX11... (whose API contains `XDrawString`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your **font path argument to `XLoadQueryFont` is wrong** (on my Linux/Debian desktop). Check with the `xlsfonts` command the right ones (they are all lowercases).

With

```
  myFont = XLoadQueryFont 
      (myDisplay,
        "-misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--9-90-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1");
```

it could work better. Try also with `"lucidasanstypewriter-bold-14"`

And most importantly **the coordinates passed to `XDrawString` are wrong.** Remember that they are the coordinates of the *baseline* of your text. And *x=0, y=0* is the *top left* corner of the window, and y is growing *downwards* and x is growing to the *right*. Hence your text is drawn off-window, above its top. So *y* should be positive and more than the font height.

Try

```
  XDrawString (myDisplay, myWindow, myGC, 15, 20, hello,
           strlen (hello));
```

As I commented, you need to handle a *lot* more events.

---

> I don't have experience with window applications on Linux.

And **to learn about GUI programming, I strongly recommend first using some [toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit) like [GTK](http://gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.io/) or perhaps [SDL](http://libsdl.org/)**.

Raw X11 programming is too hard (and by the time you'll learn it is will be *obsolete*, e.g. by [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol))), in particular because an X11 application needs to be [ICCCM](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/ICCCM/icccm.html) & [EWMH](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) compliant. Notice that the entire X11 documentation requires nearly ten thousand pages.

See also https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/

BTW, most Linux GUI applications are drawing pixmap client side and sending it to the X11 server. Read about [compositing window managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager). Drawing requests like `XDrawString`  are no more used anymore in practice. Recent font related libraries like `libfontconfig`, `libXft`,  etc are working on the *client* side.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have right, I should learn window programming with API first

Comment: PS: It's working now with changed parameters, also without a font changes

Comment: so is it already obsolete now?)

Comment: @VolodymyrBoiko Oh, you dug out some beauty of mine... Years went by and I still work on X11 based window manager, because Wayland doesn't like my Nvidia card :P